# Docmail API for ROR application for postcard

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using docmail's Simple API for sending Postcard.They have implemented this functionality recently, but I didn't get any sample code or instruction for implementation.

Thanks in advance,
Gaurav Soni

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer.Here is a sample code that can interact with Docmail Simple API methods.

```
require "base64"
require "soap/wsdlDriver"

class TestDocmailLetterSending

  def initialize(account)
   api="https://www.cfhdocmail.com/Test_SimpleAPI/DocMail.SimpleAPI.asmx?wsdl"
   @test = SOAP::WSDLDriverFactory.new(api).create_rpc_driver

   contents = open(file, "rb") do |f|
      f.read
   end

   result = @test.sendLetterToSingleAddress(
     'sUsr' => "username",
     'sPwd' => "password",
     'sMailingName' => "string",
     'sCallingApplicationID' => "string",
     'bColour' => true,
     'bDuplex' => true or false,
     'eDeliveryType' => "StandardClass",
     'sTemplateFileName' => File.basename(file),
     'eAddressNameFormat' => "FullName",

     'bTemplateData' => contents,
     'sFirstName' => first_name, 
     'sLastName'  => last_name,  
     'sAddress1' => "",
     'sAddress2' => ,
     'sAddress3' => ,
     'sAddress4' => ,
     'sPostCode' => ,
     'bProofApprovalRequired' => 'false'
   )

   end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have any RoR examples at this time - others here may be able to help, but it's essentially a SOAP webservice, with the SimpleAPI using less complex data types than the standard version.  The standard API already lets you send postcards and letters, but is more complex to use from some environments due to it's complex data types.

The **test** version of Docmail's SimpleAPI has now been updated to expose postcard calls to allow physical postcards to be send via the Simple version of the API.  *Once we're happy with the updates, we'll make them available in the **live** version too.*

Although you've probably already been through the other info on the API, here are some links/addresses in case anyone else needs them:
[Docmail API Info Page](http://www.cfhdocmail.com/webservice.html) 
Simple API **Test** Webservice & Website (for the Simple API **Live** versions, replace "Test" with "Live"): 

https://www.cfhdocmail.com/Test_SimpleAPI/DocMail.SimpleAPI.asmx?WSDL

https://www.cfhdocmail.com/Test

Hope that helps.
Will
(from Docmail)

Comment: Note: you'll need to make sure the PDF/Word file used contains 2 or less pages for postcards.

Comment: Please refer to the https://www.cfhdocmail.com/API/index.html website for latest code samples as well as API endpoints